# Execute a rule at given date htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to execute the following rule every month and leave it for only 1 hour.
So my idea is to execute maintenance on my website automatically and show a html page.

The following rule, shows `maintenance.html` to the user.

```
RewriteRule /.*$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

More specifically I want every month and the 12th day at 2AM. At 3AM i dont want to execute to rule anymore. And next month at the 12th day repeat the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} =02
RewriteCond %{TIME_DAY} =12
RewriteRule /.*$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: It is supposed to, `%{TIME_HOUR}` is only the hour part, you would have to use `%{TIME_MIN}` to take account for minutes, and/or `%{TIME_SEC}` for the seconds (or even `%{TIME}` for a timestamp). I haven't tested though, but from 03:00 it should take the value `03` and stop rewriting